# How to build an IONIC 3 app runs as a 'foreground service'?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am converting one of my own app written in Java with Android SDK to a new one based on IONIC 3. My old app starts automatically after phone boots up and runs as a foreground service.

I can see that there is an 'autostart' plugin in IONIC Native that I can use to start my app automatically after phone reboot (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/autostart/)

However, I cannot see any plugin to let my app runs as a 'foreground service'.

I need to keep my app running as a foreground service so that it can monitor some physical button actions.

Comment: How you did that with Java?

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/DavidBriglio/cordova-plugin-foreground-service ? I have the same issue and this plugin seems to handle this task

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Background Mode plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/) after using autostart. This plugin prevents going to a pause state when in background, so that way you can still execute anything in your app (like it was in foreground).

I don't know where in your app do you monitor the button pressed, if it's in a specific view, but in Ionic probably you'll need to monitor it on `app.components.ts`.

Hope this helps

Comment: this plugins stops working after 5m in android 8.0.0